# what is the diffrence b/w dls:add-document-properties and xdmp:add-document-properties as both do same work in properties of a managed doc?

Tags: versioning, marklogic

what is the diffrence b/w dls:document-add-properties  and  xdmp:document-add-properties as both do same work in properties  of a managed doc in Marklogic??
 I use both one by one on a managed doc but they give the same result.

Answer (score 0):

DLS uses the properties fragment to manage the DLS information. This is stored in document properties under the DLS namespace. Clobbering this information would make the DLS feature fail.

The version dls:document-add-properties() and associated calls fail if you try to write properties to the DKS namspace - this protecting the integrity of the system.

I would not use the XDMP version on DLS. Further to that, I would have the system with much tighter security on roles for which a DLS user's role really only had execute permissions for the DLS functions and not others that are not needed.

Answer (score 0):

In addition to David's correct answer, dls:xxx code further guarantees that operations are made only on dls managed documents, that they are locked for update during the process, that the calling user has DLS permissions on the document, that the properties are valid and non-conflicting with dls internal properties.